# if else statement for DateUtils

Tags: android, if-statement, android-dateutils

1. So before this I already get the time difference between two times.
2. Now, I want to display point that will be charged for specific time duration like this:
   in my code, time duration named as diffResult,
   if diffResult less than 30 minutes, point will be charged is multiply by 1
   diffResult =2, so 2*1 ,point will be charged is 2.
3. I wanted to use if else statement, but I got some errors. Here is my code

   ```
   pointChargeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
           Date date1 = null;
           try {
               date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeResult.getText().toString());
           } catch (ParseException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           Date date2 = null;
           try {
               date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeResult2.getText().toString());
           } catch (ParseException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           String diffResult= DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS).toString();

           if(diffResult < 30){

               int point = diffResult * 2;
               pointChargeBtn.setText(point);
           }


       }
   });
   ```

Comment: post which errors you face? and which thing user can enter?time or date? which format?

Comment: In your code diffResult is a String. Operator '<' cantnot be applied to a String.

Comment: since diffResult is a String so can't compare with integer in the if statement. Button to display time. The format is SimpleDateFormat and MINUTES_IN_MILLIS @Janvi Vyas

Comment: do I have to convert the diffResult from string to and integer? @will

Comment: @NorSakinah you can get hours from diffResult like so: diffResult.split(" ")[0] than cast it to an Integer like so: new Integer(diffResult.split(" ")[0]) . Now you have the hours as an int and can compare it like you are doing above

Answer (score 0):

Your error is:

```
 String diffResult= DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS).toString();

        if(diffResult < 30){

            int point = diffResult * 2;
            pointChargeBtn.setText(point);
        }
```

`diffResult` is a `String` so you can't compare it with a number neither multiply it

**EDIT**

You can fix it like that:

```
// difference in milliseconds
// Using Math.abs is optional. It allows us to not care about which date is the latest.
int diffInMillis = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()); 

// Calculates the time in minutes
int diffInMinutes = diffInMillis / (1000 * 60);

// if difference is less (strictly) than 30 minutes
if (diffInMinutes < 30){
    // TODO: Do something
}
```

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: But you're aware that your app will crash if there is any parsing error? You should test if both dates are not `null` and do something if this is the case (e.g. display an error message to the user), before trying to calculate the time difference